# Locating ODBC Driver 13.0 for SQL Server on Ubuntu Azure VM

Tags: python, linux, azure, ubuntu, odbc

I have a python script that requires ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server to connect and write to a SQL Server. I am trying to setup the script on a Linux VM running Ubuntu 16.04 on Azure. I am having trouble locating the location of the driver to use in my script.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) on installing ODBC and it appears to have installed successfully. However, whenever I look for where it has installed on my system, I cannot find it.

On my local machine, I am passing the information to the connection string like so:

```py
server = '{server name}'
username = '{username}'
password = '{password}'
driver = '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib'

# use following string for database connection
con = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + user + ':' + passw + '@' + host + ':' + str(port) + '/' + database + '?' + 'driver' + '=' + driver, echo=False
```

On the Linux VM, when I installed ODBC from Microsoft this was a portion of the output

```
Preparing to unpack .../msodbcsql_13.1.9.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking msodbcsql (13.1.9.2-1) ...
```

Where is the rest of that file path? When I used `find . .../msodbcsql_13.1.9.2-1_amd64.deb` it returned no results

In order for the script to function, I need to locate where the driver is on the server so I can pass that path to the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please make sure that you have installed `unixodbc-dev` via `apt-get` on Azure Ubuntu VM. Then the `pymssql` or `pyodbc` module is required by `sqlalchemy`, you can refer to the offical document [`Python SQL Driver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to install it.

Next, there is my answer for the SO thread [Microsoft Azure Data warehouse and SqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701915/microsoft-azure-data-warehouse-and-sqlalchemy/41712574#41712574) which you can refer to, and it includes the sample codes as below.

```
import sqlalchemy

connection_string = "mssql+pyodbc://<user>@<server-host>:<password>@<server-host>.database.windows.net:1433/<database>?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server"
engine = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine(connection_string)
engine.connect()
```

Or

```
import sqlalchemy
import urllib

params = urllib.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=<server-host>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database>;Uid=<user>@<server-host>;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;")
engine = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
engine.connect()
```

For more details about `sqlalchemy` with `pyodbc` or `pymssql`, please see the SQLAlchemy document for [Microsoft SQL Server](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html).

Comment: By making my `driver = 'ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server'` it worked perfectly!

Comment: Although SQL Server on Azure proposes a ODBC string with 13 I changed it to 17 because my Ubuntu 20.04 works with 17, and it works