# df.to_sql connection issue, any idea?

Tags: sql, azure

Below are my codes
I want to export a python dataframe to azure SQL

```
df

            Date  ...  Count
1     2019-09-04  ...    0
2     2019-09-04  ...    0

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:xxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=aaaaaaa;Uid=user@aaaaaaa;Pwd=$$$$$$$$$$$;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')

conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str,echo=True)

df.to_sql('users', con=engine)
```

Error below:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like that you want to save a pandas dataframe to Azure SQL Database via the function [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

There is a SO thread [Locating ODBC Driver 13.0 for SQL Server on Ubuntu Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381398/locating-odbc-driver-13-0-for-sql-server-on-ubuntu-azure-vm/55382364#55382364) answered by me to show the connection code with SQLAlchemy and `pyodbc`. So I think your code is correct.

However, just according to your error information, it seems that you did not install Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server first and just install the Python packages `pyodbc` and `sqlalchemy`. So please download the related odbc driver first from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 and install it. Then try your code again.

If you created your Azure SQL Database just now, I recommanded you need to install the `2017` version of MS ODBC driver and change the connection string with `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`( not `13` for `2013` driver version), because the MS 2013 ODBC driver not support the latest Azure Database.

Comment: Actually it also not work when change to 17
the following works, there must me so error in my coding
>>> engine = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
>>> engine.connect()
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x0B1560B0>
>>> df.to_sql('users', con=engine, if_exists='append')